# ERC721 on near deploy using rust (ink!), i'm stuck in callinf the function and pass the argument

Tags: command-line-arguments, nearprotocol

After the deploy on near and when i was try to live test for mint function the error occurs.

reference code:- docs.rs/erc721/latest/src/erc721/lib.rs.html#1-644 [link on cmt.]

when I was putting the command for near call

-terminal

PS C:\Users\aarsh\NFToken\flipper> near call dev-1674118357556-19282316843398 mint '{"id":"1"}' --accountId monish22.

Scheduling a call: dev-1674118357556-19282316843398.mint({id:1})

An error occured

SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1

```
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at scheduleFunctionCall (C:\Users\aarsh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\near-cli\commands\call.js:54:84)        
    at async Object.handler (C:\Users\aarsh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\near-cli\utils\exit-on-error.js:52:9)
```

Comment: https://docs.rs/erc721/latest/src/erc721/lib.rs.html#1-644  refere code

Comment: Looks like an error in the parsing of your JSON data by your terminal, try backspacing or use bash